# Why are SSRS (+Dundas) 2008 reports exported as PDF bigger than 2005?

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, dundas

We are creating large reports in SSRS 2008 (with Dundas) that when exported to PDF, are coming out with a file size of about 4.5MB.  The same reports in 2005 came out at just under 1MB.

Is there something configurable that can be changed?  We've experimented with setting the global DPI configuration down to 96 in SSRS, but this doesn't appear to be making a difference.